# application deployed in tomcat 7 takes 15 minutes to get connection

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, datasource

I have one application deployed in a Tomcat 7.
With a datasource to oracle ddbb configured not globally.
And we access to this datasource through a configured resource (auth container).

The problem is that when the server just started and fresh the code inside the application; ds.getConnection() works fine. But, after some time of webapp idle (more o less 1hour and half, I don't know exactly how long is it), the application takes a long time to execute that code (more o less 15 minutes). And we need to reestart the server and all the things go well.

Do you know why after a time of webapp idle the datasource takes a long time to return a connection?

The database is oracle 12g.

thank in advance,
best,
Jose Blesa

Comment: My guess is that the code is doing something weird. Have you monitored system resources like memory or CPU usage? Do they exhibit different levels of usage after one hour?

Comment: What kind of DataSource are you using? Different things can happen, maybe the ConnectionPool is full, the Connection may be in some weird state, i.e. the pool thinks it's valid but actually it's closed or something like that, ... Maybe it helps to use some validation Query. The Tomcat JDBC Connection pool for example allows to set different options for that. http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html

Comment: Hi,

the problem occurs when the application is not used. After a long time whitout any activity, the fist call to getConnection() delays 15 minutes and after that all is OK. So I think that the idle pooled connections are stealed due a something is closing the connections (there is a firewall between them) and when the application wake up, the first getConnection() call tries to use one of the 10 idle pooled connections and at the end, it creates a new connection and the things gone ok.

thanks in advance!